# How to test for an empty UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have the following code where I want to see if a particular `UIImageView` (image) is set. If not then I want to display an error message.

```
if (image==nil) {
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Image Selected" 
                                                                 delegate:nil 
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [actionSheet showInView:[[self view]window]];
        [actionSheet autorelease];
    }
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

… `imageView.image == nil` ? Or, to check for empty images, `CGSizeEqualToSize(imageView.image.size, CGSizeZero)`.

Comment: the empty image example was a bonus . :)

Comment: There's no imageView.image method at all.

Comment: There may be no imageView.image if "imageView" is a uiimage, not a uiimageview

Answer (score 7):

It may be tricky to figure out if `(UIImageView *)image` has been initialized with an image. You may want to check the image property:

```
if (image.image == nil)
```

This will work in the case where `image.image==nil` (`UIImageView` initialized by image not set) AND in the case where `image==nil` (since messages sent to nil `return nil`).

Beware local variables as well: Just because you never `alloc/init` image doesn't mean it will be nil.